# Why is this NotSerializable?

Tags: java, android, serialization

I get a NotSerializableException with the following code and I don't know why:

```
private class Entry implements Serializable {
    public int mProgress, mReps;
    public int mDays;
    public String[] mEntry;

    public Entry() {
        mEntry = new String[2];
        mProgress = mReps = 0;
        mDays = 0;
    }
}

private HashMap<String,Entry> mEntries;

FileOutputStream fos = mApp.openFileOutput("FOO", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
os.writeObject(mEntries);
os.close();
```

I caught the exception which occurred in one of the above 4 lines:

save exception java.io.NotSerializableException: com.company.app.classname

Comment: You might want to post the whole stack trace.

Comment: @CommonsWare: agreed - I cannot get this code to produce a `NotSerializableException`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect that `Entry` is an inner class, and therefore will have a reference to the "outer" class, which is probably not serializable.

Try the following:

```
private static class Entry implements Serializable {
...
}
```

Note the `static` keyword.

EDIT:

As pointed out by @Henrik, looking at the exact exception message and stacktrace often provides vital clues.  In this case the exception showed the name of the class that is not serialisable (`com.company.app.classname`) and as that class is not referred to in the `Entry` class, led me to suspect that this was an inner class.

Comment: My sandbox-experiment confirms that this is the case. As a side-note, the exception is (in my case, at least) quite informative about this: it includes the name of the outer class in the exception message, underlining the value of including stack traces even when they don't seem important.

Comment: Yep. Also since I'm new to java - I assume class Entry has to be an inner class unless I want to create its own separate Entry.java and import it right?

Comment: @Mark: Technically it can be in the same .java file and not be an inner class (it just can't be a public class).  Also, if `Entry` was in its own file but in the same package, then it doesn't need to be imported.  Personally, I think if `Entry` is not needed elsewhere and can be thought of as an implementation detail of the `classname` class, then a `private static` inner class makes sense to me.